# React router 4 HashRouter, how do I hide hash in the url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using react-router-4 HashRouter because I put my static build to AWS bucket and served through cloudfront. So essentially I do not have a server at the front end side of things to support BrowserRoute.

What I want is: `example.com/#/accounts_ to be _example.com/accounts`
In angular 1.x I would use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to achieve the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `{withRouter}` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use BrowserRouter. And I would suggest reading up on how the client and server routing works.

Using this approach, if you are planning on using anything in a production environment, you will need to configure that environment to have a fallback route to your index page to then handle client-side routing.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/foo" component={FooController}
    <Route path="/foo/bar" component={FooController} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And your webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
},
```